# How Do I Convert an Excel XLS to an Access MDB using Excel VBA

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, vba

I need to use VBA from Excel to load an Excel workbook in access and transfer it out to a database.

```
Dim acc As New Access.Application
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Test.xls"
```

I got that far and Excel crashes and has to restart.  My plan was to use the following but I can't get that far.

```
acc.DoCmd.TransferDatabase
```

Any ideas? I've googled for days and come up with nothing.

*Edit: Thanks for the responses so far
I absolutely have to use Excel VBA, unfortunately.  There is an excel spreadsheet that has a bunch of empty columns that are being recognized by the Jet engine as defined columns, too many in fact > 255 (or is it > 256?). I do NOT want to open the Excel worksheet for any reason (this takes far too long over the network).  I don't have the option or choice to format it correctly or clean it up. It's easy to convert an XLS spreadsheet into a MDB database inside of access as you all say, but that's not an option.  So like I said, I need to use VBA in Excel to manipulate the access object to convert an XLS workbook to an MDB database; Once I have this, the rest will be cake.  Thanks so much! I love this site.

Comment: Why do you have to use Excel to do this? It seems that Microsoft recommends loading the Excel file from Access.

Comment: Is this a misprint acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Test.xls" ? Surely you mean acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Test.`mdb`" ?

Comment: Brettville, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you edit your question and give us more detail? Can you give us a step-by-step of what you want to do? Are you trying to import an Excel worksheet into an Access db?

Answer (score 1):

This task is straightforward if you're able to use VBA from within Microsoft Access; e.g.:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet , , _
"tblImportFromExcel","C:\path\to\myfile.xls", True, "A1:B200"
```

`TransferSpreadsheet` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214134%28office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: I agree that this is the simplest, but couldn't the original poster just make and control an Access object from Excel?

Comment: @power: post that as an answer; I'll upvote it if there's a code sample! :-)

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the suggested solution from Adam Bernier (with the addition from PowerUser concerning using an access object from within Excel); your last comment was after those suggestions and you did not reply.

```
Dim acc As New Access.Application
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Test.mdb"

acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
    TransferType:=acImport, _
    Spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, _
    TableName:="tblImportFromExcel", _
    Filename:="C:\path\to\myfile.xls", _
    HasFieldNames:=True, _
    Range:="A1:B200"
```

(Adapt as needed, especially the HasFieldNames and Range). If this does not work, then there is probably something really wrong with your Excel-Sheet.

The only other thing I can think of (but that would mean to open the file) is to save the Excel-Sheet as XML and transform the values via XSLT in a more suitable format, then import the resulting XML. But that might be overkill (how complex is your file, how often do you need this import to proceed).

HTH
Andreas

Comment: It needs to be from within Excel

Comment: @bretville, this _is_ from within Excel (although it wouldn't make a difference if it were from e.g. Word. Just make sure in VBA you have set the reference to MS Access so that you can use its object model. Have you tried out the example?